# Is there (another) way to see more consumable items?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

Is there a way to see more consumable items in Knights of Pen and Paper?  My current list only shows the first 8 in my inventory which unfortunately does not include all my better items. (I am aware I could get rid of the worse ones:))

https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/231740/view/2922229425716096694 bespeaks to the ability to scroll "The Consumable items list is now scrollable during combat when several items are listed" but it does not work for me.

In case it matters I am playing on Steam.

[image: My Consumable List]

Answer (score 0):

I attempted scrolling again today and it did work.  However (maybe it's my mouse) but more often than not it takes more than 1 rotation of the mouse wheel, I counted up to 10 rotations before I saw any movement.  In addition this scrolling (at least for me) only did 1/5th of an item in movement.  That is to say in worse case scenario it might take 60 rotations of the wheel to scroll up or down 1 entire item (including space in between items).  And it's easy to give up and believe it's not working, it's so unresponsive.

UPDATE: The next battle I tried to do this it seemed non-functional again.  So, could be intermittantly broken as well.