# Is there a way to rearrange your inventory?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

Due to what I believe is a bug (either the game or me), I cannot scroll to see more than 8 consumable items at a time (ref [Is there (another) way to see more consumable items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395007/is-there-another-way-to-see-more-consumable-items)).

To workaround, I was wondering if there's a way to reorganize the order of your inventory.  When I equip things, the item I am removing takes that slot.  When I select and drag to an empty space or to exchange, nothing happens.

In case it matters I am playing on Steam.

[image: My inventory]